# Problems Making a Deep Copy of NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-text

I'm trying to make a deep copy of an `NSMutableAttributedString` called `text` using another `NSMutableAttributedString` called `textBackup`. Both are properties set to `@property (nonatomic, retain)`, and I create the backup as follows:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *textBackupTemp = [self.text mutableCopy];
self.textBackup = textBackupTemp;
[textBackupTemp release];
```

Then later on, when a certain scenario occurs, I need to restore the copy:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *textTemp = [self.textBackup mutableCopy];
self.text = textTemp;
[textTemp release];
```

This seems to work fine, however the next time I access `text` like the following:

```
[self.text.string characterAtIndex: self.cursor.position-1]
```

I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

The string size has changed to 1 instead of 43 like it should be. What could possibly be going on here...

EDIT: Updated the problem.

Comment: mutableCopy doesn't actually return a new instance, despite its name.  If the original object is mutable, it just returns a pointer to it and increases its retain count (if my memory serves, I know that's how it is done for regular copies).  It only returns a new object is the original object is immutable.

Comment: see my comment below to rishi @borrrden

Comment: @borrrden It's just the opposite of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a stupid error on my part, I had put `@property(nonatomic, assign)` for my `textBackup` instance variable. I changed it to `retain` and now everything works.